# Lines of JTextArea to an ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, string, swing, newline, jtextarea

How would one convert every line in a `JTextArea` into an `ArrayList<String>`? That is, how does one detect line breaks in a JTextArea?

Here is my current pseudo code implementation:

- get text from JTextArea
- Go through every char in JTextArea and adds it to a string called currentWord until it finds a line break char //(does such a thing exist?)
- When the loop detects a line break, it adds currentWord to the arrayList and sets currentWord to empty.
- After the loop ends, add currrentWord to the ArrayList.

1. Is there an easier way to do this?
2. Does this implementation scale well with size? (I'm guessing no)

Comment: Do you mean real `\n` line breaks, or breaks that just happen to occur in a long string because it renders wider than the current view?  The former is easy (`split(textvalue,"\n"`). The latter doesn't make sense as the splits would change depending on the view's width.

Comment: I would assume the former. When the user line breaks with enter, that would register as \n right?

Answer (score 10):

embrace the power of `Strig.split(regex)` and `Arrays.asList` function:

```
    String s[] = jTextArea1.getText().split("\\r?\\n");
    ArrayList<String>arrList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s)) ;
    System.out.println(arrList);
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by using `JTextArea#getText` to get ALL the text from the text area.

Once you have that, you can use `String#split`, passing `"\n"` as the value.  This will return an array of `String`'s split on the new line.

If you want to extract each word from the line, you could split it again, presumably on `" "`, which will give you each word.

You can then use `Arrays.asList` to convert this to a `List` (of words or lines) and (assuming you've already created an instance of one), use `ArrayList#addAll` to add all the `String`s to the list.

If you're only interested in each unquie word, you could use a `Set` to filter out duplicate words

Comment: I guess he needs something very simple like this:  ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(myJtextArea.getText().split("(\r|\r\n)"));

Comment: @bluebrain I've never kW JTextArea to use /r, doesn't mean you shouldn't consider it though...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, isn't it safer to use `"\\r?\\n"` for split *regex* ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, sorry again, but i think you were right at the first edit as i don't think OP is trying to read the words rather directly the line as string

Comment: @sage As I said, I've never know JTextArea to use \r as a line break, not saying you shouldn't consider it, but from experience, I've never had to use it ;)

Comment: @sage Getting hooked on the "currentWord" term

Comment: @MadProgrammer, you are probably right. I am inexperienced about JTextArea.

Answer (score 1):

```
JTextArea txArea = new JTextArea();
txArea.setText("line1\nline2\nline3");
String txt = txArea.getText();
String [] arrayOfLines = txt.split("\n");
ArrayList<String> linesAsAL = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String line: arrayOfLines){
    linesAsAL.add(line);
}
```

Or instead of adding lines to ArrayList on a loop something more elegant:

```
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(txt.split("\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String line[]=jTextArea1.getText().split("\\n");
List<String> list=Arrays.asList(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, on reflection, I might use your original algorithm like this

```
private static List<String> toList(JTextArea textArea) {
  List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(); // return list.
  if (textArea != null) {
    String val = textArea.getText(); // the text.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // for the current word.
    for (char c : val.toCharArray()) {
      if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) { // ANY white space.
        if (sb.length() > 0) { // is there a current word?
          al.add(sb.toString()); // add it to the list.
          sb.setLength(0); // clear the word.
        }
      } else {
        sb.append(c); // NOT white space, add it to current word.
      }
    }
  }
  return al; // return the list.
}
```

Comment: SrringTokenizer...really? You could just split the line again on " " or even use a regular expression for a more complicated requirement and simply add the resulting array directly to the ArrayList, would take like 3 lines at the most...just saying ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't know what I was thinking! Here's OP's algorithm; It's not bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
final List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(textArea.split("\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scanner s = new scanner(JTextArea.getText());
while (s.hasNext()) {
   arrayList.add(s.nextLine())
}
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to your answer, please?