# How can I get the line where a specific word is written on a JTextArea in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm trying to iterate through a JTextArea and get the line where a specific word is written so I can insert the line number into a table or an array but I don't have a clear idea on how to address it.

I haven't tried too much until now for the same reason that I don't have the idea of how to do it.

Comment: Details: Does the text field use word wrap? Are you interested in the line as measured by hard line-breaks or by hard *and soft* breaks (a la word wrap)? Note that it is usually best to ask a question *after* you have done significant research and have tried something.

Comment: No, it doesn't use word wrap, I am interested on hard-line breaks

Comment: I have my doubts about it, because the line number could differ based on the so many different variables

Comment: *"I am interested on hard-line breaks"* - then discard the text area and search the text itself, maybe breaking the text down into an array/list of lines

Comment: Rob Camick (site user camickr) has or had some text utilities that might be of use in adding line numbers to text areas, but I can't find the link

Comment: if you use the getLineOfOffset() method you should use the "Documents" getText() method since it will only contain a "\n" for each line so the offset will be returned correctly. If you use the getText() method of the text area the String may contain "\r\n" which could result in an incorrect offset for the string location.

Comment: You could also try looking at [Text Utilities](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/). You can't use any of the methods directly, but the code in the methods may help you iterate through each Element (line of text) in the Document to search for the word in question.

Comment: @user16320675, Oops, I made a wrong statement. If you start with an empty JTextArea or JTextPane and just type text, then the getText() method with only return a "\n". However, if you use the `read(...)` method to read a file into a JTextArea or JTextPane the text area works the same however the JTextPane.getText() will return the "\r\n" on Windows. I made an unnecessary comment since might only be an issue with a JTextPane and reading from a file.

Comment: Thanks to all people with comments, I'll upload the solution on how I did it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you will need to get the text of the JTextArea. Here, I will put it as an array where each line in the array is a line in the JTextArea. I found this code from [this guy on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20432540/18154064).

```
String lines[] = jTextArea1.getText().split("\\r?\\n");
```

*This uses [regexes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), kinda hard to explain so there’s the documentation for you.*

Afterwards, you can [loop through the lines of the array](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arrays_loop.asp) and look for x word. To find x word in a string, you can use [`String.contains(String);`](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_contains.asp)

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if(lines[i].contains(x);
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

Here, the line where the word is located is `i`.

There is a problem though. There could be multiple of the same word. There are multiple ways to *fix* this: keep the last one; keep the first one; keep of them; and many others.

To keep the last one, you could assign a variable to the value of `i`. As that variable’s would get changed each time that word comes up, the last time the word would appear would be the value of that variable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if(lines[i].contains(x))
        myVar = i;
}
```

To keep the first one, you can create a boolean variable that is first assigned to true and when you find the word in the string, simply put it to false. Add an if statement and yeah, should work.

```
boolean xShowedUp = false;
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if(lines[i].contains(x) && !xShowedUp)
    {
        myVar = i;
        xShowedUp = true;
    }
}
```

To keep all of them, you can make an array and add the value of `i` to the array when you find the word in the string.

If you would like to learn more about the the JTextArea, you can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#:%7E:text=A%20JTextArea%20is%20a%20multi,it%20can%20reasonably%20do%20so.)!

*This is one of my first answer, please forgive me for any misspellings of any errors in my explaining. Thanks!*